# MVC 2 EditorForModel() rendering foreign key table names

Tags: linq-to-sql, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010, data-annotations

I have an interesting problem and wanted so see if anyone else has seen this. I've created a MVC 2 site using Visual studio 2010 beta 2. I'm using linq to sql data model objects with data annotations.

In my data model objects I'm using [ScaffoldColumn(false)] attribute to exclude the foreign key ID's from rendering to the UI when I use the EditorForModel method. For some reason the UI is rendering the foreign key table name.

e.g.   if the foreign key is AccountID, i see the "account".

I wonder if this is a bug in the editorformodel or if I need to use a different/additional data annotation attribute to instruct editorformodel to not render anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Linq to SQL classes will have a property for the foreign key itself (AccountID) as well as an EntitySet property for the related records in the Accounts table. If you open up the auto-generated designer.cs file under your linq to sql dbml - you can view all the properties of each class. I think by default the templated helpers are only supposed to generate an editor for the first level of properties. There is a "deep-dive" option that will extend the generated editor to more levels of properties. Check out [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) on the subject (near the end of the post).

In general, trying to throw your auto-generated Linq to SQL classes into your View or annotate them with attributes gets pretty hairy. It might be worth checking into [strongly typed view models](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx) where you could specify only the properties you're interested in displaying in your view.

Comment: Ah kewl! I see what you mean here. Thank you.